# ASP.NET Core Remote Validation not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, remote-validation

I tried adding some simple Remote validation to my webpage (ASP.NET Core 2.2, MVC), but it does not show on GUI.

Code from my Client (view) model:

```cs
[StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Max input is 32 characters.")]
[Remote(action: "CheckTaxNumber", controller: "Clients")]
public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
```

Code from my View:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Tax No.: </label>
   <input class="form-control" asp-for="TaxNumber" maxlength="32" />
   <span asp-validation-for="TaxNumber"></span>
</div>
```

Code from my Controller:

```html
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")] 
public IActionResult CheckTaxNumber(string taxNumber)
{
   var check = _clients.CheckTaxNumber(taxNumber);

   if(check.Result)
   {
      return Json(true); 
   }
   else
   {
      return Json(check.ErrorMessage);
   }
}
```

After the user changes the input field (for the tax numbe) the validation fires and returns a result (true/false + error message), but it does not show on the form.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean `return Json(check.ErrorMessage);` is called while debugging? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test, fail to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yes, return Json(check.ErrorMessage) is called while debugging. I have other validation on the form (like "required" for example and it works/shows). What kind of demo do you have in mind?

Comment: Share us a project which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: My project has a data layer linked to our SQL server (which is only accessible via our active domain) so I cant share it, because it will not work outside of our environment. Is there some other way we can try and figure this out? Is there something additional I can check for while debbuging?

Comment: You could create asp.net core built-in template with your view model and controller, try to reproduce your issue with this new template.

Comment: Tao, when I was preparing a template I noted an error in my checking method (CheckTaxNumber). After I corrected the error validation works  as expected.

Comment: How should I mark this thread/post? Should I delete it?

Comment: You could post your answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the code posted works. There was an error in the check method I was calling (CheckTaxNumber). After I fixed the method the validation works as expected.

Comment: There was error in this line: `var check = _clients.CheckTaxNumber(taxNumber);` in the CheckTaxNumber method. There was nothing wrong with the remote validation itself or the way I used it in cshtml. Since it's more than a year ago I do not remember the exact error...